# Angular 4 hide button

Tags: angular, button, frontend

When i click the 1st button how i can show 2nd button and hide 1st button, and want to click 2nd button and then show 1st button and hide 2nd button

```
<button class="btn" type="button" name="button" (click)="follow()">follow</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" name="button" (click)="followed()">followed</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think it's more of making the two buttons visible/hidden as supposed to enabling/disabling them.

This is probably what I would do.

```
<button class="btn" type="button" *ngIf="isVisible" name="button" (click)="toggle()">follow</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" *ngIf="!isVisible" name="button" (click)="toggle()">followed</button>

export class AppComponent { 
    public isVisible: boolean = true;
    toggle() {
        this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<button class="btn" type="button" [disabled]="!disableBtn" name="button" (click)="follow()">follow</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" [disabled]="disableBtn" name="button" (click)="follow()">followed</button>
```

In component

```
export class AppComponent { 
  disableBtn : boolean;
  follow(){
      this.disableBtn = !this.disableBtn;
  }
}
```

Here is the working **[plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wr4l8oT9EANk8ZV16ec2?p=preview)**